# Best practice to parse multiple config files

Tags: pyparsing

What would be the best practice - if there is any - to parse multiple config files?

I want to parse the mysql server configuration and also write the configuration again.

The configuration allows to issue multiple lines like:

```
!includedir /etc/mysql.d/
```

So the interesting thing is, that some configuration may be located in the main file but other may be located in a sub file.

I think pyparsing only works on ONE single file or one content string.

So I probably first need to read all files and maybe restructures the contents like adding headers for the different files...

```
====main file====
[mysql]
....

!includedir /etc/mysql.d/

====/etc/mysql.d/my.cnf====
[client]
.....
```

I would only have one pyparsing call.
Then I could parse everything into one big data object, group the file sections and have the file names as keys. This way I could also write the data back to the disk...

The other possibility would be to parse the main file and programmatically parse all other files that were found in the main file.
Thus I would have several pyparsing calls.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

In your pyparsing code, attach a parse action to the expression that matches the `include` statements, have it parse the contents of the referenced files or directory of files, then merge those results into the current parse output. The parse action would make the successive calls to `parseString`, your code would only make a single call.

See this new example added to the pyparsing examples directory: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/include_preprocessor.py

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints. I will look into this later and respond accordingly!

Comment: So basically, any data that needs to be passed back to the parent caller (from the function executed via its `setParseAction`) would need to be stored outside of pyparsing class?  Or can we use a 'return value` statement inside the setParseAction function?

```

Comment: I don't really understand the question, but parse actions frequently return values that are internally created, or even modify the parsed results in place.  There are several examples in the pyparsing GitHub repo (https://www.github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) that show how to work with parse actions. SO isn't designed for Q and A in these chat threads.Take a stab at writing what you are thinking of, and if it isn't working post a new question.

Comment: After perusing the pyparsing example, the closest one that I found is not implemented yet in verilog.  https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/95ad65fe6a962cc8ea519abefde85f0bc1f75b7e/examples/verilogParse.py#L41

Haven't understood how to insert these additional data stream where the include statements are.

Comment: Well the macroExpander.py is in the same vein, but '#include' is a little different, so I'll add this example to the next release:: https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/blob/master/examples/include_preprocessor.py  Only works in Python 3.x, since it uses pathlib.