# How to resume parsing with new open file

Tags: python, bind, pyparsing, dhcp

ISC-style (Bind9, DHCP) configuration file makes uses of `include` statement(s).

```
/* dhcp config */
include 'host_group.conf'
...
```

With PyParsing, how do I open this include file, start with that new input, and resume parsing with its current parsing state?

It is important to keep track of which include file the error occurred at.

I have checked the following answers:

- [Best practice to parse multiple config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021524/best-practice-to-parse-multiple-config-files)

The answer to the alleged duplicate question does NOT answer the tracking of error code in relation to its file, included or not.

Comment: It may be simpler to run a pre-processing step that will recognise `include` directives and dump the included file's contents right in the current file. Then, after all these directives are resolved, parse the preprocessed text.

Comment: Yep, and lose my context of which include file may be the contributing parse error.

Comment: No, this would not be a duplicate because it pertains to ISC-style config file like ISC-Bind9 or ISC-DHCP.